# How would you translate 'you just blew my mind'

Tags: значения

If I wanted to say 'you just blew my mind', or maybe in other words, 'I'm trying to wrap my mind around what you just said/did,' what might be some possible translations?

Answer (score 3):

- "Ты только что взорвал мой мозг"
- "Я пытаюсь врубиться в то, что ты только что сказал"

*Врубиться/врубаться* is a bit rude slang for "осознать/понять" - "to realize/to understand".

Comment: Можете ещё добавить «вынес мне мозг[и]».

Answer (score 3):

Quite possible that "**взорвал мой мозг**" became quite common due to vocabulary limitations of the modern youth which is under enormous pressure from the West and its culture (and language) and trying to cope with it *using literal translations* of *pop culture idioms* previously unknown to them.  Nothing we can do about that.

The expression "**вынес мне мозги**" or "**снёс мне мозги**" sounds a bit smoother and actually closer to the intention.

As to **wrapping one's mind** *around something*, I'd use "**охватить** *что-то* **умом**" or "**постичь** *что-то*"

Answer (score 2):

*Я не въезжаю*; *Я не догоняю*; *Я не врубаюсь*; *Я не вкурил* - slang; means "I really can't understand".

*Ты мне мозг взорвал*; *Ты мне мозг вынес* - rather modern (mostly teenager) slang; seems like a calque from English.

The following may also be usable:

*Ну ты даёшь* - colloquial; "This is not what I expected of you".

*Да ты гонишь!* - slang; "You tell me shit"; may also mean "You got me surprised; Is this for real?!".